# Scaling of JavaScript canvas looks strange after rotation

Tags: javascript, canvas, rotatetransform, scaletransform

I have an html canvas that is stretched to the browser window dimensions in an JS script. I want to keep the fit of the canvas to the window dimensions (via ctx.scale or ctx.setTransform), but rotate it by 90° when the window is vertical, i.e. window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth. However, I see some strange behavior in the vertical case and don't know what I'm missing.

My JavaScript code is below:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("GameCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canv_start_w = canvas.width;
canv_start_h = canvas.height;

// drawing functions
function set_canvas_bg() {  
    ctx.fillStyle = "lightblue";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
function draw_line() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth="3";
    ctx.strokeStyle="black";
    ctx.moveTo(canv_start_w/16, canv_start_h/2);
    ctx.lineTo(15*canv_start_w/16, canv_start_h/2);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}
function draw_circ() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle="black";
    ctx.arc(canv_start_w/2, canv_start_h/2, canv_start_w/10, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}

// canvas transformation functions
function resize_canvas() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}
function scale_ctx() {
    var smaller_dim = Math.min(canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var larger_dim = Math.max(canvas.width, canvas.height)
    var xscale = larger_dim/canv_start_w;
    var yscale = smaller_dim/canv_start_h;
    ctx.setTransform(xscale, 0, 0, yscale, 0, 0);
}
function rotate_ctx(deg) {
    ctx.rotate((deg/360)*(2*Math.PI));
}

function update() {

    resize_canvas();
    scale_ctx();

    // distinction: vertical or horizontal window?
    if (window.innerWidth < window.innerHeight) {
        // CASE 1: vertical
        rotate_ctx(90);
        ctx.translate(0, -canvas.width); // move back into view
    } else {
        // CASE 2: horizontal
        rotate_ctx(0);
        ctx.translate(0, 0); // move back into view
    }

    // drawing elements to canvas
    set_canvas_bg();
    draw_circ();
    draw_line();
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

update();
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the canvas please?

Comment: problem is around setTransform and rotate simultaneously, you need to rotate around center after applying scale (calculate it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime the canvas dimensions are changed, the context transformations (i.e. rotate, scale) are deleted. The working script can be found and experimented with here: https://jsfiddle.net/nicoa47/3fsan6c0/

The three-part solution is

(1) to **reset the transformations at the beginning of each update loop** via

```
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
```

(2) to **translate the context to window center and translate back** after rotating/scaling (which ensures rotation around window's center) via

```
ctx.translate(window.innerWidth/2, window.innerHeight/2);
// rotate...
// scale...
ctx.translate(-window.innerWidth/2, -window.innerHeight/2);
```

In the vertical case, the arguments of the second translate need to be swapped.

(3) to **change the scaling function based on the current scale**. That means, create new variables

```
var canv_current_w = window.innerWidth;
var canv_current_h = window.innerHeight;
```

Which keep track of the last frame's dimensions, i.e. at the end of the update loop set:

```
canv_current_w = window.innerWidth;
canv_current_h = window.innerHeight;
```

Again, swap values in the vertical case. Replace canv_start_w, canv_start_h with these new variables in the scale function.